Flutter форма согласия appodeal
Подскажите как изменить текст формы согласия. сейчас она выглядит так.   Это готовое решение  appodeal, а мне нужно убрать Test Asd.
В гугле ничего не получилось найти. Есть только информация,  о том что, appodeal добавили готовое решение формы согласия


Кажется "Test Asd" это название компании/команды/продукта в appodeal?

да, там должно было быть название компании,.
